# Expected value of Compond Poisson Process

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, poisson-process

I'm having trouble understanding why we do this:

## Information

**Definition.** A stochastic process $\{X(t),t\geq 0\}$ is a compound Poisson process if 
$$X(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} Y_i, \qquad t\geq 0$$
where
$\{N(t),t\geq 0 \}$ is a Poisson process and
$\{Y_i , i = 1,2,3,\ldots\}$ are independent and identically distributed random variables.

## Expected Value

This is what they did
$$\mathbb{E}(X(t))=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X(t)\mid N(t))) \qquad \text{law of total expectation} \\ = \mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}Y_i\mid N(t) \right] \right\}\\ = \mathbb{E}(N(t)\mathbb{E}(Y_1)) = \lambda t \mathbb{E}(Y_1).$$

## Query

I don't understand why in the first equality, they used the law of total expectation. As in, what's the point? Can't I simply have
$$\mathbb{E}(X(t)) = \mathbb{E} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right)= \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} \mathbb{E}(Y_i) \qquad \text{by independence} \\ =N(t)\mathbb{E}(Y_1)$$
which is clearly not correct, but why isn't it correct? Also, how did they go from the second equality to the third?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$ \operatorname{E}\left( \sum_{i=1}^3 Y_i\right) = \operatorname{E}(Y_1+Y_2+Y_3) = \operatorname{E}(Y_1) + \operatorname{E}(Y_2) + \operatorname{E}(Y_3) = 3 \operatorname{E}(Y_1). $$ That's how they got from the second line to the third. $\qquad$

Comment: Ah so the main idea is that since we condition on $N(t)$, this means we fix $N(t)$?

Comment: You did not state it but the assumption that the jump sizes $Y1,\ldots$ and the number of jumps $N(t)$ are independent is critical for the result.

Comment: @Therkel : Specifically where in the argument do you use that independence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The move that is illegal is:
$$
\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}Y_i\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N(t)}\mathbb{E}(Y_i).
$$

This would be true if $N(t)$ were nonrandom, but it isn't true if it is random. As Shalop indicated in the comments, it doesn't even make sense since the RHS of the equation is random but the LHS isn't.

But it is in fact true that $$ \mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}Y_i\right) = \mathbb E(N(t))\mathbb E(Y_1),$$ as your first solution showed. This result is a case of [Wald's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation)

As for how they got from the second line to the third, they used the fact that since we're conditioning on $N(t)$, it is effectively a constant. Then $$ \mathbb E\left(\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}Y_i\mid N(t)\right]\right) = \mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}\mathbb E\left[Y_i\mid N(t)\right]\right) =\mathbb E\left(N(t)\mathbb E(Y_i)\right) = \mathbb E(N(t))\mathbb E(Y_i)$$

where in the last two equations we used independence of $N(t)$ and $Y_i$ and the fact that all the $\mathbb E(Y_i)$'s are the same.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know of Wald's Equation and I didn't realise we treat $N$ as a constant if we condition on it...   
Question - why is $N(t)$ and $Y_i$ independent? Isn't $N(t)$ a poisson process and $Y_i$ are iid as well?

Comment: They are independent by (perhaps unstated) assumption.